# MySQL automatic conversion on lowercase

Tags: mysql

I have multiple web services that write data inside a database table.
I'd like to automatic convert uppercase strings into lowercase ones, for a specific field.
Is there any mysql function that performs this task?

Suppose this is the table:

```
id | name | language
```

Sometimes, inside the language field, web services write an uppercase string (IT).
I want to convert it into a lowercase string ("it"), directly inside MySQL.

thanks

Comment: Do you actually need to convert the case of the inserted data, or simply perform case insensitive lookups?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Define [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html) on the table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER lcase_insert BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.language = LOWER(NEW.language);

CREATE TRIGGER lcase_update BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.language = LOWER(NEW.language);
```

Then update the existing data:

```
UPDATE my_table SET language = LOWER(language);
```

Comment: Why I didn't thought it before! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

you could use:

```
LOWER("some_string");
```

See: [LOWER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower)

Did you mean something like this..

Added:
You could convert into lowercase while inserting the data in table, like:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (name, language)
    VALUES ( "Some Name", LOWER( "SOME VALUE" ) );
```

Or a better solution would be converting the value to be inserted to language field to **lowercase** from your server side script before inserting to db.

You could do the automatic conversion thing using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) though, but i suggest using LOWER() function during fetching your data from table, like:

```
SELECT LOWER(language) AS language FROM your_table_name
```

Comment: +1, because this is what is to be used, though I suspect the OP asks for the way to automatically fold case.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I cannot modify the system application due to business rules. I mean a function applied to the table structure.