# SugarCRM - Force records to uppercase?

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm using SugarCRM with a custom module as a CRM solution, i'm just wondering if there's a way i can force everything to be recorded to the database in uppercase?

For ease of use for the admin team, i'd prefer if this was done automatically in Sugar if possible, so when the records are exported the data is all formatted as caps?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This is possible but not without a little bit of coding.  You would either need to add triggers to your MySQL installation to convert all data to upper case when it is added to the DB, or alter the save() function in SugarCRM to convert all the data to upper case before it is sent to the DB.

This link shows how to set up a trigger, it details a lower case conversion but you just change LOWER to UPPER and it works the same way.

[MySQL automatic conversion on lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795021/mysql-automatic-conversion-on-lowercase)

As far as the second idea, I think a before_save logic hook is the way to go.  the link below details how to do that.

http://cheleguanaco.blogspot.com/2009/06/simple-sugarcrm-logic-hook-example.html

either of these solutions are going to take someone with database or PHP coding skills.