# How can i set mysqli default column structure to be uppercase from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I need to save data into a MySQL column, let's assume the column name is "first_name". So how can I save the data in Uppercase by default?

Is there any way where I can set the column value to default to uppercase, so every time a data inserted from any script it will save in uppercase automatically.

Comment: mysql is the database. Mysqli is an API to connect to a mysql database using php

Comment: Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263272/capitalize-first-letter-mysql

Comment: Hello @Siva, Thanx for the reply but I need to save it from the database only. Is there any way where I can set the column to default uppercase, so every time a data inserted from any script it will save in uppercase automatically

Comment: What do yu mean by all that? Uppercase all inserted values on inserting? Why not do that in your application?

Comment: Hello @Nico Haase, My concern is to make database column work as default to save data in uppercase whether it is saved in lowercase.

Comment: Have you tried using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795021/mysql-automatic-conversion-on-lowercase?

Comment: For example, we can set a column default value to anything, just like that can we set anything in the database that takes values in uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

use UPPER() function in times of selection you dont need to push uppercase in db

```
select UPPER(first_name) from table_name
```

if you need intimes of insert then use same function intime of insert

```
 INSERT INTO table_name (first_name)
 VALUES (  upper( 'name_first' ) )
```

Though i prefer conversion in times of selection

Comment: Hello @Zaynul, Thanx for the reply but I need to save it from the database only.  Is there any way where I can set the column to default **uppercase**, so every time a data inserted from any script it will save in uppercase automatically.